# Why are my donut sprinkles so small?

Tags: modeling, mesh, geometry-nodes

[image: donut]

I'm following the donut tutorial by Blender Guru. I'm struggling with the sprinkles which do show up on the icing but are way smaller than the cylinder I made. It almost looks like dust. I searched and checked almost every similar question and anwser online to no avail. Any ideas how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: You can try applying the Scale of your Icing object (Ctrl+A/Scale) (you'll need to adjust the Thickness of the Solidify modifier). An other solution would be to adjust the Scale parameters of the "Instance on points" node.

Comment: hi adjusting scale parameter solved my problem thank you. blender is a sophisticated tool for me since i am a beginner, and your anwsers gave me lot of help

Comment: ...that's the hundred thousandth question regarding this donut tutorial :D ...and many fail because of the same problem. I've never seen the video, but I'm afraid it doesn't seem to be a very good tutorial video. However, the question here is definitely a duplicate, and there are many answers here on BSE that answer this exact problem in different ways. The answer, in a nutshell, is to simply apply scaling to the objects being instantiated.